# SQLSTATE[HY00] error when a run artisan migrate in a dockerized laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I tried to dockerize a laravel app but running into issues when I try to run artisan migrate. When I when I get a  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=4306
DB_DATABASE=osbee
DB_USERNAME=osbee
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

docker-compose

```
   db:
        image: mysql:5.7.22
        container_name: db
        restart: unless-stopped
        tty: true
        ports: 
            - "4306:3306"
        volumes: 
            - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment: 
            MYSQL_DATABASE: osbee
            MYSQL_USER: osbee
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
            SERVICE_TAGS: dev
            SERVICE_NAME: mysql
        networks: 
            - laravel
```

dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

Comment: I can see your database and username are niqao both

Comment: @ThaiNguyenHung correct it, still having the same issue

Comment: Pls change DB_PORT in .env to 3306